# run multiple functions in a single cfselect bind

Tags: coldfusion-8

I am try to run a javascript function after my cfselect bind has executed. Is there any way I can achieve that? Here is my statement.

cfselect name="artType" id="artType" size="1" query="qArtType" display="the_value" value="id"

cfselect id="allValues" name="allValues" multiple="true" bindonload="true" bind="cfc:art.getArt({artType})" size="10" style="width: 100%;"

The first select "artType" drives the second select "allValues".

I want to call a javascript function once my bind has executed. It is called listAll(). Is there any way I can do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you will not be able to do that. You might try and bind to a javascript function that handles the ajax call, but it certainly adds to the amount of code you'll be writing. This might put you on the right track if you're willing to do that [here](http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2008/12/16/Ask-a-Jedi-Mixing-ColdFusion-8-binding-with-jQuery). This also uses jquery to handle the ajax call..